# Auto accepting the .ics files in outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook, icalendar

I am trying to generate iCalender files in asp.net. An ics file with below details is downloaded for the user and when user clicks it it opens the outlook calender entry which the user have to Save and close again.

Can we make it a one stop process where user just have to click the file and  it goes to outlook calendar directly?

Please note the 'Automatically accept meetings' setting in outlook is turned on. What am i missing then.

Thanks for the help.

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20160115T144939Z
DTSTART:20160111T040000Z
DTEND:20160111T050000Z
SEQUENCE:0
UID:12579759-1604-47e8-ac51-d1ae3d17425d
CREATED:20160115T144939Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160115T144939Z
LOCATION: Meeting Room2
DESCRIPTION:Meeting Number 2
SUMMARY:Meeting Number 2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: The "END:VEVENT" and "END:VCALENDAR" properties must be on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks but it is like that in actual file..just a missing <br> in this post.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is you can't accept meeting of some one else through ICS. But you can give a try for `STATUS: CONFIRMED`